# Let $I=[0,1]$ and let $\mathbb{R}^I =\{f : f :I \to \mathbb{R}\}$ have the product topology. Is $A=\{f \in X : f(x)\le f(y), x<y \}$ closed in $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $I=[0,1]$ and let $X = \mathbb{R}^I =\{f : f :I \to \mathbb{R}\}$ have the product topology. Is the set $A=\{f \in X : f(x)\le f(y), x<y \}$ closed in $X$?

$A$ is the set of $f \in X$ such that $f$ is increasing so the complement $A^c$ is the set of $f \in X$ such that $f$ there exists $x<y \in I$ such that $f(x)>f(y)$

If $f_0 \in A^c$, then I am to find a open set $U$ containing $f_0$ such that $f_0 \in U \subset A^c$.

What kind of revelation I am to make to find this open set $U$?

Comment: The sentence *...so the complement $A^c$ is the set of $f \in X$ such that $f$ is decreasing, that is $f(x)>f(y)$ for all $x<y \in I$...* is wrong as a function that is not increasing may not be decreasing either.

Comment: It should be "there exists" I think?

Comment: Can you update your question based on your comment?

Comment: @Gödel But our space is not metrizable - why do you think we can characterize closed sets in terms of _sequences_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_0 \notin A$. We have to find an open subset $U$ of $f_0$ for the product topology such that $f_0 \in U$ and $U \cap A = \emptyset$.

As $f_0 \notin A$, it exists $0 \le x_0 \lt y_0 \le 1$ such that $f(x_0) \gt f(y_0)$. Let $a = \frac{f(x_0) + f(y_0)}{2}$ and

$$U_{x_0} = \{g \in \mathbb R^I \mid g(x_0) \gt a\}, \, U_{y_0} = \{g \in \mathbb R^I \mid g(y_0) \lt a\}.$$

$U_{x_0}, U_{y_0}$ are open subsets of $\mathbb R^I$ for the product topology, and both contain $f_0$. Therefore $U = U_{x_0} \cap U_{y_0}$ is also open and contains $f_0$. Moreover for $g \in U$, we have

$$g(x_0) \gt a \gt g(y_0)$$ implying that $g$ can't be increasing. We've proven that $A$ is closed.

Comment: What is the motivation to define $a$?

Comment: Just to have a number that is between $f(y_0)$ and $f(x_0)$. $a$ is just in the middle!

Comment: But what is the motivation to get a number in the middle?

Comment: @Ylvas. We want $f(y_0)<r<f(x_0)$ so that no member of $U=U_{x_0}\cap U_{y_0}$ is increasing. Hence $U$ is a nbhd of  $f_0$ that is disjoint from $A,$ implying $f_0\not\in\overline A.$

Comment: To ensure that maps belonging to $U$ are not increasing as shown below in the proof.